# Codeigniter: Store value of a dropdown into session variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a dropdown in the login page which fetches company codes and it's respective ID as value. I need to store this particular value (ID) in a session variable so I may use it throughout site. So that when that particular company is selected I may be able to view the details of that particular company. If there is an alternate method for this, kindly let me know.

**MODEL:**

```
public function login ()
{
    $user = $this->get_by(array(
    'company_id' => $this->input->post('company_id'),
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),
), TRUE);

$this->session->set_userdata($user);
    if (count($user)) {
        // Log in user
        $data = array(
            'username' => $user->username,
            'id' => $user->id,
            'loggedin' => TRUE,
            'is_admin' => $user->is_admin,
            'company_id' => $user->company_id
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<tr>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td><select class="form-control" id="company_code" name="company_code" required>
          <option value="0" selected>Select Company</option>                      
          <?php foreach($locations as $location){
            $selected = $user->company_id==$location->company_id?"selected='selected'":'';
            echo "<option $selected value='".$location->company_id."'>".$location->company_code."</option>";
        }?>
        </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('username','','class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name"'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_password('password','','class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password"'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Log in', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

I want the above `company_id` to be posted into a session variable so it maybe used throughout the program. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what problem you are facing? In Your model code you are saving the data into session

Comment: It is showing as 0 when I try to fetch it, Is the code on the top right?

Comment: The value of the `company_id` is showing 0, I have updated the model section of the code. Is there some sort of clash with the code below?

Comment: how are you fetching it ?like  `$this->session->userdata("company_id");`

Comment: Yes, is there a conflict with `$data` array?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $selected=$this->session->userdata("company_id")==$location->company_id?"selected='selected'":'';
```

Comment: Nope, `company_id` is still showing 0, when I selected `company_id` as 2

Comment: did you loaded session library in constructor like `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: also update `<option value="0" selected>Select Company</option>`  to `<option value="0">Select Company</option>`,  remove selected attribute of first option

Comment: I included it right now within the login function, still taking the value 0